# Command to validate the connection between Datastage client and server

Tags: server, client, datastage

I am stuck in middle of a project where we are validating the installation of different softwares. My problem is that is there any proper commands for **validating the connectivity between datastage client and server**. Did some google and research but could not find a good solution. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Connectivity you can check with `ping <server_address>` command as this is same as other Client Server system. Now, Actual check is whether the datastage user is allowed to access the Datastage Server.

You can solve this problem by using dsjob from client server

```
dsjob -domain <DOMAIN> -server <SERVER> -user <USER> -password <PASSWORD> <PROJECT> -joblist
```

If you get job list in return your user can connect with DS server

Comment: Thanks @Atul Singh. I really appreciate it.